# Which exactly MaxReceivedMessageSize should be increased

Tags: wcf, iis-7, web-config

Looks like this question has been asked thousand times already, but each person's configuration problems are different. I have WCF server that serves images and also receives upload image requests. When uploading images I'm getting error 400 when size is more then 65k.

I turned the trace on the WCF and I'm getting exact error

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element.

I know that I need to increase this parameters but I'm just can find where is it supposed to be in my web.config file. Here is what I have in web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ReportTransferServiceBehavior" name="ReportTransferService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ReportTransferService" contract="IReportTransferService"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="ReportTransferServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500" maxConcurrentInstances="500" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <domainServices>
      <endpoints>
        <add name="json" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.JsonEndpointFactory, Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000" />
      </endpoints>
    </domainServices>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ReportTransferService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000" maxBufferSize="2000000" transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2000000" maxArrayLength="2000000" maxBytesPerRead="2000000" maxNameTableCharCount="2000000" />
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The URL I'm sending images (HTTP POST) is `hostname/ReportTransferService.svc/UploadImage`. Looks like it's using some kind of default binding and not `basicHttpBinding` configured for bigger size.

Anyone can tell me what's wrong with my web.config?

**Update: Resolved**

I had to specify fully qualified name for ReportTransferService in service configuration and serviceBehavior configuration and added whole new webHttpBinding section with similiar limits and pointed service to use this binding.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Once I faced a weird issue like this. I've specified every config element a higher value as you did. At last one of my colleague found the issue is because of specifying the complete full name(Namespace.Type, Assembly) in either contract or service type (i'm not sure) but after removing the assembly name everything worked fine.

Comment: Can you remove the protocolMapping and give a try

Comment: @Mark - I get 500 error on both download and upload

Comment: you are getting that error after removing the protocolMapping? Can you trace and post the error?

Comment: Something like this: The endpoint at 'http://xxxxxx/Site/ReportTransferService.svc' does not have a Binding with the None MessageVersion.  'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior' is only intended for use with WebHttpBinding or similar bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service section should have fully qualified names as shown below:

```
     <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ReportTransferServiceBehavior" name="namespace.ReportTransferService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ReportTransferService" contract="namespace.IReportTransferService"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
```

Comment: If I do just these two changes I'm getting error 500 System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException on both image download and upload.

Comment: Note that your readerQuotas settings needs to be the same on both client and server. 500 is internal server error indicating that there was some problem on the server method during processing. You can enable tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on your service to get the exact reason for the error

Comment: Client is JS web page. Trace is on. I'm getting the following error: The endpoint at 'http://host/Site/ReportTransferService.svc' does not have a Binding with the None MessageVersion.  'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior' is only intended for use with WebHttpBinding or similar bindings.

Comment: Makes sense as you are trying to perform a REST call via SOAP binding. Just change the binding type from basicHttpBinding to webHttpBinding and accordingly change the readerQuotas for the webhttpBinding as well for large files. (Assuming that you are performing a ajax call from client using HttpWebRequest class or similar)

Comment: Aha... Added same section as I had for basicHttpBinding to webHttpBinding and pointed service to use it. Looks like it solved it. I'm gonna clean it up and confirm it, and will mark your answer. Thanks a LOT!